# Why has my domain controller remembered its dns/dhcp settings from before a reinstall?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp, domain-controller

Recently due to a hardware upgrade/replacement we powered down the whole domain (this is a small office so it's all on one server (ADDS, DNS & DHCP)) but when we powered up the network couldn't access the Internet...

Fast forward a little and one of the guys had messed up the config trying to fix it.

I've decided to remove the roles as we weren't sure what's been done and reinstall them, then promote the server back to domain controller but it still seems to have retained previous settings and it won't deal out a valid ip configuration to itself to access the Internet and I'm out of ideas now.

Does anyone know why it's retained them after I removed the roles? It's a Windows server 2012, I genuinely thought I could flatten it and recreate the domain overnight and I'd be the hero! But it Hasn't quite worked out like that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `it won't deal out a valid ip configuration` ? Can you ping the gateway ? DNS resolution is OK ?

Comment: `it won't deal out a valid ip configuration to itself` - Why is the server configured as a DHCP client? `I genuinely thought I could flatten it and recreate the domain overnight and I'd be the hero!` - Of course... save for all of the disjoining and rejoining the domain, and permissions issues, and user profile issues, and etc., etc. due to that approach.

Comment: We really need a "you have no idea of what you are doing" close reason...

Comment: A "reinstall" will preserve those settings, a "fresh install" will not. There is a difference between the two. All domain controllers need a permanent IP address assigned to them for a multitude of reasons.